# Trie Implementation in C: Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, data-structures, trie, cs50

I'm currently doing CS50 from Harvard and the goal is it to load a dictionary into any data structure in the fastest way possible. For this problem set I'm using a Trie.

The logic behind my code is as follows:

1. Read one character at a time.
2. Check in the childnode of the trie if the character already exists, if it equals NULL, we allocate some space to it.
3. The curser is set to the childnode we just allocated space to.
4. If we reach the end of a word ("\n") we set the boolean value to true and completely reset the curser to its initial value (which we have stored previously in the curser->root).

I have tried several implementations, some of them had a few logical errors which I was not happy with and some gave me segmentation faults when I had a big dictionary.

Below is the code of my latest implementation, basically what happens is that it's fine with loading the first word into the trie structure, but it fails at the second. The problem then lays into me setting the new node value to the childenode (to which we allocated some free space). The logic behind this is it to obviously connect the tree and move on to the next node. This is the code which I think is wrong:

```
curser = curser->children[tolower(ch) - 'a'];
```

But the thing is, it worked in some of my other implementations, only with this one it stopped working all of a sudden and gave me a segmentation fault after the first word. As I said, I'm a beginner in coding so please enlighten me and criticize my implementation! Thanks a bunch.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    bool end;
    struct node* children[27];
    struct node* root;
    struct node* next;
} node;

//global variable used to check the number of words in the trie
int totalwords = 0;

//root node
node* curser;

int ch;

int main(void)
{
    FILE* dict = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open dictionary\n");
        return 1;
    }

    curser = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    curser->root = curser;

    for (ch = fgetc(dict); ch != EOF; ch = fgetc(dict))
    {
        if (ch == '\0')
        {
            curser->end = true;
            curser = curser->root;
            totalwords++;
            printf("%i\n", totalwords);
        }

        else
        {
            if (isalpha(ch))
            {
                if (curser->children[tolower(ch) - 'a'] == NULL)
                {
                    curser->children[tolower(ch) - 'a'] = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                }
                curser = curser->children[tolower(ch) - 'a'];
            }

            else if (ch == '\'')
            {
                if (curser->children[26] == NULL)
                {
                    curser->children[26] = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                }
                curser = curser->children[26];
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(dict);
    return false;
}
```

Edit:

Another question I have is why my in my current code it is not able to detect the Null Terminator \0 but it can detect a new line \n? I need to be able to detect the null terminator in order to get the correct amount of words. Any suggestion as to what is wrong?

Comment: I really highly recommend using a debugger to find out what is going on in this kind of program, specially since you are coding in C and are dealing with segfaults. For starters it will show you precisely what line is causing the segfault and being able to inspect your variables at runtime and step through the program line by line is very helpful. If you are using an IDE it probably comes with a debugger. If not, you can use something like GDB.

Comment: To add to what @hugomg says - don't write any more code at all until you know how to use a debugger.  If you cannot debug, you cannot develop software.

Comment: @MartinJames: I think you are being too harsh there. Using a debugger is not the only way to debug code.

Comment: I'm using GDB all the time fyi and even used valgrind (which gave no hint as to where the seg fault came from). But I'm getting used to GDB and find it a great tool to find the errors in my code (opposed to making a dozen of printf statements :P)

Comment: psst: it's spelled `cursor`, not `curser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `curser->root=curser;` You should do the following:

```
curser->end=false;
curser->next=NULL;
for(i=0;i<27;i++)
    curser->children[i]=NULL;
```

When you initialize memory for curser it is not guaranteed that it's members will be automatically allocated to `NULL` and `false`.

Do this `everywhere` for a node you are allocating `memory dynamically.`

You also need to set `child->root=curser->root` for every children you are allocating memory dynamically

Comment: You also need to set child->root = curser->root for each new children.

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot Ayush! Didn't think of doing this. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Another question I have is why my in my current code it is not able to detect the Null Terminator \0 but it can detect a new line \n? I need to be able to detect the null terminator in order to get the correct amount of words. Any suggestion as to what is wrong?

Comment: Didn't work sadly. It's still not able to detect the null terminator. The thing is, it can detect a space, but that will lead to errors in the counting of words, as it would count a blank space as a word.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if this relates to Pset5 of CS50, and you are trying to implement the loading of a dictionary.  As it happens, you are using the `fgetc` function to read a single letter from a text file, and not from memory.

When you are reading from memory, there will be a `'\0'` NULL terminator for the word. However, with `fgetc` you are using stdio to read from the file and the `'\0'` terminator does not exist in that file. Since the words in the CS50 dictionary are stored one word per line, and all lines end with a `'\n'` ("new line"), it can be found that way.